# What is this 2-line communication protocol?

Tags: signal-processing

I tried a wide variety of protocol decoders in pulseview including UART, I2C, and SPI, but nothing seems to match.  This is captured from communication between a topside controller and the mainboard in a spa manufactured recently.  The mainboard is a [Balboa VS501Z](https://spacare.com/productimages/pdfmanuals/balboa/VS501Z.pdf).  There is digital data on only two lines.

[image: pulseview]
[image: pulseview]
[image: pulseview]

Here is the pulseview file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/t4ydsxx4p733l22cqp9sq/pulseview.zip?rlkey=rxnknq3nydj85qke9apipqzux&dl=0

Comment: Neither line looks like a clock. This is a strange comms protocol.

Comment: possibly tx and rx

Comment: It's interesting that the signal doesn't seem to change when the panel is disconnected, so I don't think it's a two-way communication.

Answer (score 0):

Physical layer is probably IRDA SIR. Lower trace is Tx signal, upper trace is clock leakage on a disconnected Rx signal.

Comment: I figured it out eventually.  I failed to use the ground connection on the logic monitor.  After I connected ground the signals were very different, and easy to decode.